# Iteration through list of dataframes by grouping variable (lapply / map)

Tags: r, lapply, purrr, tibble

First of all I am going to paste the class of my dfs before getting

```
class(group_1)
[1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

I am going to paste 3 pieces of code of my datasets, you have to know that I UNGROUPED the data

```
g1 <- structure(list(id = c(110104019, 120715032, 120715020, 50203029, 
70111022, 140102087, 120715020, 120715033, 140102088, 110113007, 
120715029, 111201026, 110110005, 120715026, 110104028, 140103029, 
110110005, 50527001, 111201026, 130108008), sexo = c(1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), grup_int = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), gen = c("pcsk9", 
"abca1", "s18", "il10", "il8ra", "ccl3", "il10", "s18", "nr1h2", 
"cyp27a1", "lag3", "ppard", "lag3", "ptgs1", "nr1h3", "abcg1", 
"cyp27a1", "scarb1", "vcam1", "mcp1"), time = c("1", "1", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "1", "1", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "1", "3", "3"), Ct = c(NA, 17.781, 10.964, 24.152, 16.463, 
22.747, 23.815, 10.809, 19.229, 18.642, 18.803, 16.583, 21.288, 
16.209, 21.11, 19.298, 17.278, 20.491, 23.792, 23.226), dCt = c(NA, 
5.907, -1.151, 12.796, 3.965, 10.522, 11.7, -1.544, 5.867, 5.97, 
7.252, 5.122, 9.234, 5.412, 9.244, 7.361, 5.224, 8.201, 12.331, 
11.859), RQ = c(NA, 2.356, 0.936, 1.244, 0.464, 1.28, 1.537, 
1.256, 0.486, 1.159, 2.176, 1.244, 1.462, 1.486, 1.344, 0.662, 
1.865, 1.376, 2.358, 1.035)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

g2 <- structure(list(id = c(110104019, 120715032, 120715020, 50203029, 
70111022, 140102087, 120715020, 120715033, 140102088, 110113007, 
120715029, 111201026, 110110005, 120715026, 110104028, 140103029, 
110110005, 50527001, 111201026, 130108008), sexo = c(1, 1, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), grup_int = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), gen = c("pcsk9", 
"abca1", "s18", "il10", "il8ra", "ccl3", "il10", "s18", "nr1h2", 
"cyp27a1", "lag3", "ppard", "lag3", "ptgs1", "nr1h3", "abcg1", 
"cyp27a1", "scarb1", "vcam1", "mcp1"), time = c("1", "1", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "1", "1", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "1", "3", "3"), Ct = c(NA, 17.781, 10.964, 24.152, 16.463, 
22.747, 23.815, 10.809, 19.229, 18.642, 18.803, 16.583, 21.288, 
16.209, 21.11, 19.298, 17.278, 20.491, 23.792, 23.226), dCt = c(NA, 
5.907, -1.151, 12.796, 3.965, 10.522, 11.7, -1.544, 5.867, 5.97, 
7.252, 5.122, 9.234, 5.412, 9.244, 7.361, 5.224, 8.201, 12.331, 
11.859), RQ = c(NA, 2.356, 0.936, 1.244, 0.464, 1.28, 1.537, 
1.256, 0.486, 1.159, 2.176, 1.244, 1.462, 1.486, 1.344, 0.662, 
1.865, 1.376, 2.358, 1.035)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
> g2 <- group_2 %>% dplyr::ungroup() %>% dplyr::select(id, sexo, grup_int, gen, time, Ct, dCt, RQ) %>%  slice_sample(n = 20, replace =F) %>% ungroup() %>% dput()
structure(list(id = c(110606056, 110104017, 60901024, 110113008, 
110113008, 140103036, 110104017, 50705001, 110104027, 50109026, 
110104029, 110104024, 50203022, 110104017, 140103035, 140103035, 
130106037, 130102010, 50203022, 110606056), sexo = c(1, 1, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), grup_int = c(2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), gen = c("ldlr", 
"tnf", "pparg", "ptgs1", "cxcl8_il8_", "mcp1", "il1b", "ptgs1", 
"cyp27a1", "ccl3", "cxcl8_il8_", "ccl3", "gapd", "cd40l", "lag3", 
"ptgs2", "pcsk9", "ccl3", "slc2a3_glut3_", "nr1h3"), time = c("3", 
"1", "3", "1", "3", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "3", 
"3", "1", "3", "1", "1", "1"), Ct = c(18.842, 18.926, 23.787, 
18.165, 15.629, 24.504, 16.084, 17.259, 19.718, 22.88, 15.522, 
21.688, 16.776, 17.413, 18.828, 17.398, NA, 20.422, 15.503, 20.641
), dCt = c(6.749, 6.537, 12.334, 6.027, 2.92, NA, 3.973, 5.619, 
5.988, 10.377, 4.101, 8.885, 4.207, 5.302, 7.953, 5.974, NA, 
8.827, 2.776, NA), RQ = c(NA, 1.188, 0.7, 2.065, 1.589, NA, 1.597, 
1.6, 3.858, 0.99, 0.845, 2, 1.293, 1.135, 2.542, 1.067, NA, 1.218, 
2.86, NA)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))

g3 <- structure(list(id = c(130106034, 60901027, 60901035, 130106034, 
50203013, 50430001, 50109025, 50203012, 50203006, 60901027, 130106034, 
50203019, 50203014, 120715012, 50109019, 140103019, 140102090, 
140103019, 110104023, 60901031), sexo = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), grup_int = c(3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3), gen = c("nr1h2", 
"cd86", "cd86", "adrb2", "il8ra", "ldlr", "mcp1", "chuk", "olr1", 
"nampt", "s1pr3", "ido", "lrp1", "cxcl2", "ptgs2", "cxcl2", "ppard", 
"gapd", "ptgs1", "pcsk9"), time = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "3", 
"3", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "1", 
"3", "1"), Ct = c(18.987, 18.701, 17.983, 17.064, 14.62, 19.71, 
24.713, 17.419, 25.328, 12.745, 21.264, 19.5, 17.102, 22.794, 
18.162, 23.335, 17.332, 15.329, 17.895, NA), dCt = c(5.995, 6.199, 
5.644, 4.072, 3.298, 6.907, 12.762, 5.607, 12.525, 0.243, 8.272, 
7.451, 5.007, 11.107, 5.3, 11.513, 3.353, 4.113, 5.42, NA), RQ = c(0.858, 
1.931, 1.235, 0.885, 1.013, 1.52, 1.05, 1.263, 1.538, 0.822, 
0.122, 1.209, 2.202, 1.321, 1.277, 2.002, 4.713, 1.198, 6.309, 
NA)), row.names = c(NA, -20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Intermediate steps with question vital for the next steps ( i am going to go for 1st approach). Creating the list of dfs

```
# 1st approach
list_1 <- list(g1, g2, g3)

# 2nd - vector
g_all <- c(g1, g2, g3)
```

Now what I want to achieve, this would be for an individual dataframe

```
descriptive_g3 <-lapply(split(g3, group_3$time), function(x) {
    x %>% 
    group_by(gen) %>% 
    get_summary_stats(c(dCt,RQ), show = c("mean", "sd", "median", "iqr", "min", "max")) 
  })
```

I would like to pass it to the list of dfs (grouping by gen). I've tried

```
#lapply
lapply(list_1, function(df) df %>% group_by(gen) %>% 
    get_summary_stats(c(dCt,RQ), show = c("mean", "sd", "median", "iqr", "min", "max")))

#or
lapply(groups, function(x) aggregate(gene~dCt, x, c( "mean", "sd", "median", "iqr", "min", "max")))


#with map

list_1  %>% 
map(., ~ group_by(., gen)) %>% map(., ~get_summary_stats(c(.$dCt,.$RQ), show = c("mean", "sd", "median", "iqr", "min", "max")))
```

```
#Desired output

gen variable    n   mean    sd  median  iqr min max
abca1   RQ  50  1,595   0,86    1,436   1,068   0,241   4,395
abcg1   RQ  50  1,363   0,617   1,18    0,718   0,329   3,017
adrb2   RQ  50  1,177   0,317   1,141   0,5 0,27    2,059
b2m RQ  50  0,761   0,248   0,714   0,321   0,166   1,39
cav1    RQ  50  1,294   0,77    1,155   0,711   0,239   4,527
ccl3    RQ  50  1,261   0,558   1,154   0,568   0,267   2,934
cd36    RQ  50  1,367   0,453   1,32    0,553   0,373   2,562
cd40l   RQ  50  1,212   0,431   1,147   0,498   0,257   2,129
cd68    RQ  50  1,403   0,464   1,377   0,598   0,347   2,678
cd86    RQ  50  1,177   0,377   1,116   0,501   0,333   1,932



Thank you for help!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want to achieve?

```
library(tidyverse)
list_1 |> 
  map_dfr(~ .x |> 
        group_by(gen) |> 
        rstatix::get_summary_stats(c(dCt,RQ), show = c("mean", "sd", "median", "iqr", "min", "max"))
  )
```

**Output**:

```
# A tibble: 94 × 9
   gen     variable     n   mean     sd median   iqr    min    max
   <chr>   <chr>    <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 abca1   dCt          1  5.91  NA      5.91  0      5.91   5.91 
 2 abca1   RQ           1  2.36  NA      2.36  0      2.36   2.36 
 3 abcg1   dCt          1  7.36  NA      7.36  0      7.36   7.36 
 4 abcg1   RQ           1  0.662 NA      0.662 0      0.662  0.662
 5 ccl3    dCt          1 10.5   NA     10.5   0     10.5   10.5
```

Comment: It works but still getting a list of tibbles that I need to get individually

Comment: Can you show your Required Output, is it a List or one df?

Comment: Dataframes or tibbles as you showed for each group. This is way in lapply there is the split option

Comment: I am sorry, but I still do not get what end result you would like to have..

Comment: I edited the post. As I said is like the tibble or the dataframe you posted, but not inserted into the list. This is why I am struggling to "release" them from the list, but somehow I cannot access to the list and split it, don't know why because many times with $ operator I can access to the elements within the list

Comment: And you wan to group by `gen` or by `gen` and `time`?

Comment: What happens if you use `map_dfr` instead of `map`?

Comment: Seems to work! I was grouping by both of them. Now I can split the df easier than the list.